# Masking a UIImageView doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, mask

I have a `UIImageview` set up:

```
let picture = UIImageView(frame: imageFrame)
picture.image = UIImage(named: image)
```

You can see it here:

[image]

Now I want to mask it a constant size, because I's going to be random pictures with random sizes, so I've created a UIView:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGRectGetMaxY(menuLine.frame) + HeightForSize * 0.05, width: view.bounds.width, height: HeightForSize * 0.9)
let mask = UIView(frame: frame)
mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

When I just add the subview to my view it looks like this:

[image]

But when I try to mask it:

```
picture.maskView = mask
```

It looks like this, what is going wrong here?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest not masking at all. You can set the size of your imageView to a fixed size, then use the property `contentMode` to adjust how it displays your image. I'd recommend `ScaleAspectFill` guessing as to how you're trying to use this.

Comment: Do you have some code as an example, so I know how to do it, it's the first time I'm working with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView respects contentMode which would likely serve your purpose here easier than a mask. Set your imageView to the fixed size you want all images to fit in. If you want the image to squeeze in and show black bars if its too tall for example, use `UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit`. but more likely what will look best is `UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill`. It will maintain the aspect ratio of your image and scale until it fills the imageView box you've created. Play with the two modes and others to see their effects.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

More info on various contentModes you can try here.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontentmode